Changing convexity by changing metrics
I was wondering if for a given functional $F$ on some space $X$, is it possible to construct explicit metrics $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ such that $F$ is convex w.r.t $d_1$ while $F$ is non convex w.r.t $d_2$. Furthermore, is there any relationship between the set $\Sigma_1$ of critical points to $F$ w.r.t $d_1$ and the set $\Sigma_2$ of critical points w.r.t $d_2$?
Here convexity is in terms of geodesic convexity, that is, different metrics induce different geodesic interpolation, resulting in (possibly) different convexity results for the same functional.
Here C.Ps are the points such that the first variations of which are zero.
A concrete or even explicit example will be greatly appreciated. Just feel super hard to imagine the geometry.

What do you mean by a "space"? Your notation suggests that it is a vector space, but you are confusing metrics and norms. Also, do you fix the topology on $X$?

@MoisheKohan Thanks for your careful reading. I didn't distinguish norms with metrics too much in my original post and now I edited them into metrics. I didn't see how the topology plays a role explicitly here, as if one has the metric, thus defines its "convex combination", then define the convexity of a function. From my perspective, that is enough.

You need a smooth structure to define the 1st variation.

You should also clarify the meaning of convexity. The one I know is only for geodesic metric spaces (the restriction of $F$ to every geodesic is convex). With that definition, the 2-point set is an obvious counter-example. Ditto any countable set with at least two distinct elements. For a slightly more interesting example, take the constant function on a set of cardinality of continuum.

I found a relevant research paper Convexity of Sets and Quadratic Functions on the Hyperbolic Space and will follow up once I get some ideas.
